# SQL Like formulas in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I currently have a small table in excel, and i am looking to create a summary table that displays "total visits with a width over 1024" and "total visits with a width of 1024 and below". But i would like this to operate within a formula as this table will be updated on a weekly basis and i would like a certain amount of the work automated.

Is this possible? i have already looked into `=SUMIF`, came out all zeros, and i would like to avoid a long string of `=IF`'s.

[image: Table]

(Note, i am aware i have spelt height wrong, this is what happens when your messing with google analtytics and excel first thing in the morning)

Comment: Would Pivot Table interest you?

Comment: Have you looked at the database functions?  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/database-functions-HP005199654.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are the formulas that you can use -

"total visits with a width over 1024"

=SUMIF(B2:A10,">"&1024,E2:E10)

"total visits with a width of 1024 and below"

=SUMIF(B2:A10,"<="&1024,E2:E10)

where B column represents width column and  E column represents visits column